# I want to convert the information of a table into a 2x2 matrix

Tags: excel

I want to convert the information of a table into a 2x2 matrix
That is, the top table is converted into the bottom table in the image.
Can anyone help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OPTION 1:** Use the `MAKEARRAY()` function (Office 365 only)

```
=LET(colHeaders, D1:G1, rowLabels, C2:C4, values, D2:G4,
h, ROWS(values),
w, COLUMNS(values),
MAKEARRAY(h*w, 3, LAMBDA(r,c,
   LET(
      _r, MOD(r-1, h)+1,
      _c, ROUNDUP(r/h, 0),
      IFS(c=1, INDEX(colHeaders, _c), c=2, INDEX(rowLabels, _r),
         TRUE, INDEX(values, _r, _c))))))
```

**Or**, with a single data range specified:

```
=LET(data, C1:G4,
cols, TAKE(DROP(data,, 1), 1),
rows, DROP(TAKE(data,, 1), 1),
vals, DROP(data, 1, 1),
h, ROWS(vals),
w, COLUMNS(vals),
MAKEARRAY(h*w, 3, LAMBDA(r,c,
   LET(
      _r, MOD(r-1, h)+1,
      _c, ROUNDUP(r/h, 0),
      IFS(c=1, INDEX(cols, _c), c=2, INDEX(rows, _r),
         TRUE, INDEX(vals, _r, _c))))))
```

It's a little bit longer but requires less user input for the necessary ranges. Cheers!

**Results:**

[image: makearray.png]

**OPTION 2:** Use VBA to "Unpivot" the data (compatible with older versions of Excel)

```
Option Explicit

Sub UnpivotData()

'Load the current data range into an array
    Dim currentData As Variant
    currentData = ActiveSheet.Range("C1").CurrentRegion.Value

'Set the dimensions of the output data
    Dim lRows As Long, data As Variant
    lRows = (UBound(currentData, 1) - 1) * (UBound(currentData, 2) - 1)
    ReDim data(1 To lRows, 1 To 3)

'Transpose the data, column by column, row by row
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, rowId As Long
    For j = 2 To UBound(currentData, 2)
        For i = 2 To UBound(currentData, 1)
            rowId = rowId + 1
            data(rowId, 1) = currentData(1, j)
            data(rowId, 2) = currentData(i, 1)
            data(rowId, 3) = currentData(i, j)
        Next i
    Next j

'Write the transposed data to the output range
    With ActiveSheet.Range("J1")
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Resize(UBound(data, 1), UBound(data, 2)).Value = data
    End With

End Sub
```

The above code assumes the table begins in cell `C1`, then outputs the results to cell `J1` on the same sheet. Adjust those two range references to meet your needs.

After new data has been added to the table, run the code again to automatically clear the previous results and output the new results. Insert a button or shape on the worksheet and assign the macro to it for quick access.

**Results:**

[image: unpivot_data.png]

Comment: tnx bro. i use office 2007. can i check in excel 2007?

Comment: @omidSistani This one won't work with Excel 2007... I'll see if I can do something in VBA.

Comment: @omidSistani I've updated my answer to include a secondary option using VBA, which should work with Excel 2007.

Comment: its simple sample data. my real data its big. m*n grid. this is ok for my real data?

Comment: It will work with any number of columns and rows of data, as long as there’s only one header row at the top and one column field on the left. It will output to a range 3 columns wide by n rows high. However, if you have more than one column on the left that need to remain fixed, then the code will need to be modified slightly to account for that. I recommend trying it on a COPY of your file first, in case anything goes wrong. I tested it with 262,144 rows of data, formatted like your sample above, and it output 3 columns x 1,048,576 rows in just over 3 seconds.

Comment: Also, if the sample data provided above does not accurately reflect the layout of your real data, then I recommend you start a new question using a sample that is a clear and accurate representation of your real data, along with the expected results. Again, if you are unsure about anything, make a BACKUP COPY of your existing file to test with, in case it doesn’t work as expected.